# Weird behaviour in IIS 7.0 - System.DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, iis-7, active-directory

I am facing a weird issue in IIS 7.0:

I have the following virtual directory in IIS:
[image]

**and only Windows Authentication mode is enabled on the virtual directory in IIS**

Now if I try to get associated DirectoryEntry for TestV/Folder/file.aspx in this manner:

```
string vDir = @"/TestV/folder/file.aspx";

            DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC/1/ROOT" + vDir, @"adminusername", @"password");
            dir.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
```

I get the exception: 
"The system cannot find the path specified"

Now if I go back to IIS and then perform the following steps:
Right click on TestV/Folder *and enable Anonymous authentication mode and  then disable it again*

Right click on TestV/Folder/file.aspx *and enable Anonymous authentication mode and  then disable it again*

Essentially i just performed some manual access on the aspx file Testv/Folder/file.aspx.

After the above steps if i re run the program, the code is successfully able to access the directory entry and successfully prints the name (file.aspx)

What is the problem here?

One more information:

I see this behavior on IIS 6.0 also. So it appears like until and unless I do some manual operation in IIS for a folder/file in virtual directory, it does not create the corresponding metadata in the active directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to the problem (with some help from one of my colleagues)

Here is the solution: 
1. The program needs to add (pseudo?)entries to the IIS metadata before it access the file/folder under the virtual directory, before we access the entry:

```
try
            {
                // make pseudo entries:
                DirectoryEntry folder = rootDir.Children.Add("Folder", "IISWebDirectory");
                folder.CommitChanges();
                file = folder.Children.Add("File.aspx", "IISWebFile");
                file.CommitChanges();
            }
```

Then voila it works

PS:

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC/1/ROOT" + vDir, @"adminusername", @"password");
dir.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
dir.RefreshCache();
```

**Directory.Refresh does not help**

Comment: You can use the static DirectoryEntry.Exists method to see if the entry exists.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you call RefreshCache() right after the third line?

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC/1/ROOT" + vDir, @"adminusername", @"password");
dir.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
dir.RefreshCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly an answer I would point out that System.DirectoryServices is not generally used to interact with IIS.  While it can give you access to IIS settings, WMI is generally a better choice.